# Slot based appointment scheduling using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

I'm trying to create an appointment booking system like calendly.com, where end users can select their preferred time slots from the listed ones.

I pretty much know the workflow and schema for this.
I'm using Postgres with Prisma, my database tables include slots, appointments (includes slot_id), etc.

```
model Slot {
  id          String   @id   @default(cuid())
  date        DateTime
  startTime   DateTime
  endTime     DateTime
  isAvailable Boolean
  
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}


model Appointment {
  id        String   @id   @default(cuid())
  slotId    String
  slot      Slot     @relation(fields: [slotId], references: [id])
  
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
}
```

---

Now, I'm confused about how should I handle slots, their generations, etc. If I ask users to create slots for each day, it won't be a good experience.

What I want is, we just ask user for their preferred slot duration (e.g. 30 minutes) and automatically generate slots.

Comment: Before moving on, check your data types: A timestamp range that includes both start and end, makes much more sense. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html